# Emacs; C-x C-j before loading dired, dired-x

Tags: emacs, require, autoload, dired

Was trying to reduce number of `require`s in my `init.el`.

However, in `dired-x`, there is the awesome `C-x C-j` = `dired-jump`, which jumps to the directory of current buffer. It is natural to want to use `C-x C-j` even if we haven't loaded `dired` and `dired-x` yet. But then it is undefined.

How to reconcile?

In other words, I run into this problem because of the following concoction I am experimenting with:

```
(setq-default dired-omit-files-p t)          ; The old way was messy
(setq dired-omit-files "^\\.?#\\|^\\.$")     ; I like `..' in my dired
(setq dired-details-hidden-string "")
(add-hook 'dired-load-hook
          (lambda ()
            (load "dired-x")
            (when (locate-library "dired-details")
              (load "dired-details")
              (dired-details-install)
              )
            ))
```

I wondered if there was a magic autoload for the function, though I don't really understand these. That is, in `dired-x.el`, I found

```
;;;###autoload
(defun dired-jump ...
```

But really, these are a little over my head, so I abandoned it.

I made a "simpler" solution, was going to delete this, but have a feeling that others will like this, so will make the question and answer for you. Comments and other strategies are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(dired-x) Optional Installation Dired Jump` <kbd>RET</kbd>

> In order to have `dired-jump` and `dired-jump-other-window` (*note
>   Miscellaneous Commands::) work *before* `dired` and `dired-x` have been
>   properly loaded you should set-up an autoload for these functions.  In
>   your `.emacs` file put

```
(autoload 'dired-jump "dired-x"
  "Jump to Dired buffer corresponding to current buffer." t)

(autoload 'dired-jump-other-window "dired-x"
  "Like \\[dired-jump] (dired-jump) but in other window." t)

(define-key global-map "\C-x\C-j" 'dired-jump)
(define-key global-map "\C-x4\C-j" 'dired-jump-other-window)
```

I'm not sure why the `dired-x` library remains separate from the default functionality. That `;;;###autoload` cookie only has an effect if the Emacs build process looks at it (the autoload statements resulting from such comments generally end up in one of the `loaddefs.el` files), so clearly that's not happening (and presumably on purpose, but your guess is as good as mine as to why).

Comment: Thank you... I think my solution has too much potential for breaking things. I prefer lines such as these which are more resilient to changes and reordering of the init file.

Answer (score 0):

The following simple solution simply defines `C-x C-j`, but will be overwritten as soon as `dired` -and thus- `dired-x` are loaded.

```
;; if dired(-x) is not loaded, C-x C-j is undefined
(defun undefined-c-x-c-j-loads-dired-and-jumps ()
  (interactive)
  (load "dired")
  (dired-jump))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-j") 'undefined-c-x-c-j-loads-dired-and-jumps)
```

Comment: This solution may not work well given small changes or reordering of your lisp.

Comment: This is a naive implementation of autoload.

Comment: @event_jr, ah, I think I see what you mean, especially if my redefining had been about `dired` or `dired-x`, rather than the key-binding. I will consider trying to justify keeping a slight edit of it in my config, as an exercise. Thanks for the observation!